# OpenGL object sorting

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I recently asked a question about rendering "glass" voxels in my game, and I was told I need to render my glass in back to front order, which makes sense to me. I've been Googling a little bit, and I can't decide if OpenGL can render back to front for me, or if I have to do it manually.

I've found sites that tell me to use different types of blending, and some sites say just disable depth testing, which I know I have to do. But do I have to manually sort my geometry? Does this mean I have to sort it according to its position on the z axis? The only problem is that the camera angle changes, so I don't know if I need to sort on all axis.

Comment: To do this properly, you should find the projected positions for your geometry, and then sort by the depth (Z) that produces. Often this is inadequate because it would assume that your object can be represented by a single point and cannot nicely handle overlapping objects, but in the case of a voxel engine you should be fine if you use the centroid as the sort point.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a dumb drawing API not a scene graph. You tell it to draw something and as soon as it's on the framebuffer OpenGL already forgets about it. Things are drawing in the order as drawing commands are passed to OpenGL.

Which essentially means: You'll have to do the legwork. But since you have to properly prepare a drawing pass anyway (frustum culling, asset allocation, state change minimizing preordering, etc.) this doesn't mean a lot of extra work.

Of course if you treat OpenGL like something it is not, namely a scene graph, your results will be sub-par.

Comment: I understand it isn't a scene graph, I just didn't know if it would sort my geometry for me. I have one last question, do I always sort along the z axis? Or do I have to sort along the axis the player is looking at?

Comment: @opiop65: How could it sort geometry if it doesn't store the geometry? OpenGL had to be a scene graph so that it could do the sorting. When you ask about which axis to sort along to, well, along the Z axis in view (=eye) coordinates. Depending on your view that may be a different axis in world coordinates. Just take the Z column of the modelview matrix and use it as operand in a scalar (=dot) product with the positions, the result is the square of the distance; you don't have to take the square root for sorting, since x⟼x² is a strong monotonic function.

Comment: I realize that now, sorry. So just to be clear, I always sort on the same axis? It will never switch? I just get the geometry that's furthest away on the "z" axis and render it, then keep incremementing along the "z" axis until I get to the closest position to the player?

Comment: @opiop65: Well, it depends on how you define "Z axis". Which Z axis are you talking about? There are infinitely many, since there are infinitely many coordinate systems relative to view space. Maybe you should not think in terms of an axis, but distance from the point of view (it suffices to test for the distance from the near clipping plane).

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your geometry according to your camera FOV/angle and then sort that on the z axis to find out the render order.

Comment: Well yes, but if I move the camera, do I have to still render front to back from what I'm looking at? For instance, camera angle starts at 0 on the rotation y axis, so z is straight ahead. If I rotate 90 degrees on the y axis, the x axis is straight ahead. So, would I sort on the x axis? Or always on the z?

Comment: You need to sort in camera space, this means your Z value you want to sort by is Vector4.DotProduct([ox, oy, oz, 1], viewMatrix.Column2). If it's column 2 or row 2 depends on the client-side API (your Java classes and methods for matrices etc.). For OpenTK it's just like baove.